# how to create a second a4 page in codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am writing a simple invoice web tool. 
Invoices should be in the size of A4. 
My Controller:

```
$this->load->view('static/print_header');
$this->load->view('static/print_invoice', $data);
$this->load->view('static/print_footer');
```

`$data` are my invoice items positions like:

HEADER

Pos ---- Item ---- Price 
1  **item1** 10€ 
2  **item2** 10€
3  **itemitem** 20€

FOOTER

If I have to many items (or they have to much text) items will go inside Footer Section and I can't create a right A4 page.

**How can I change my Controller to get something like this:** 

For eg.: 2 Pages if to many items: 
Page1: 
HEADER

Pos ---- Item ---- Price 
1  **item1** 10€ 
2  **item2** 10€
3  **itemitem** 20€

FOOTER

Page2: 
HEADER

Pos ---- Item ---- Price 
4  **item3** 10€ 
5  **itemitemitem** 40€
6  **itemitem1234** 20€

FOOTER

**EDIT: Add invoice code**

```
  <div id="content">
    <div><span style="font-size: x-large;"><strong>Invoice</strong></span></div>
    <hr />
    <div>
      <table style="width: 100%" id="invoice_task_list">
        <tr style="background:#eee;">
          <td style="width:8%;"><b>Pos.</b></td>
          <td style="width:47%;"><b>Description</b></td>
          <td style="width:15%;"><b>Date</b></td>
          <td style="width:20%;"><b>Hours</b></td>
          <td style="width:10%;"><b>Sum</b></td>
       <?php 
        $pos = 1;
         foreach( $items as $it): ?>
         <tr>
          <td style="width:8%;"><?php echo $pos; ?></td>
          <td style="width:47%;"><?php echo $it->invoice_item_text; ?></td>
          <td style="width:15%;">
          <?php if ($it->invoice_item_type == 3) {$date = date('M Y', strtotime($it->invoice_item_date)); } else { $date = date('d.m.Y', strtotime($it->invoice_item_date)); } ?>
            <?php echo $date; ?>
          </td>
          <td style="width:20%;"><?php if ($it->invoice_item_time != '0') { if ($it->invoice_item_type == 1 or $it->invoice_item_type == 2) echo gmdate('H:i', $it->invoice_item_time);}; ?></td>
          <td style="width:10%;"><?php echo number_format($it->invoice_item_sum, 2, ',', ' '); ?> €</td>
        </tr>
        <?php $pos++; ?>
        <?php endforeach; ?> 
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          <td> Total (netto): </td>
          <?php $netto = $sum['invoice_item_sum']; ?>
          <td style="text-align: right;"><span class="currency"><?php echo number_format($netto, 2, ',', ' ') ?> €</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          <td> Tax 20.00% </td>
          <td style="text-align: right;"><span class="currency">
          <?php $tmptax = (($sum['invoice_item_sum'])/100)*$invoice['invoice_tax']; ?> 
          <?php echo number_format($tmptax, 2, ',', ' ')?> €</span></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td colspan="3">&nbsp;</td>
          <td> Total (brutto): </td>
          <td style="text-align: right;"><span class="currency" style="text-decoration: underline; font-weight: bold;">
          <?php $total = ($sum['invoice_item_sum'])+((($sum['invoice_item_sum'])/100)*$invoice['invoice_tax']); ?>
          <?php echo number_format($total, 2, ',', ' ')?> €</span></td>
        </tr>
      </table>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like more of a css issue than a php/codeigniter issue.

Make sure you have a clearfix after your invoice container:

```
.clearfix {
    float:none;
    clear:both;
}
```

And that you have the correct page break settings for printing.

```
@media print {
    .footer {page-break-after: always;}
}
```

Note that an A4 piece of paper is 2480 x 3508 pixels, so make sure you CSS is adjusted for that!

---

**Edit (After Clarifications):**

There are a couple of different ways to determine whether or not your need to additional header/footer for another page. I'm going to go with what I think would be the simplest. If your rows are uniform in that (20) rows make up a whole page, then you can do a simple check and loop your views.

```
//Note that you'll have to specify only putting 20 records here
if ($rows->num_rows() > 20) {
    for ($i = 0; $i < $rows->num_rows(); $i += 20) {
        $data['start'] = $i;
        $data['end' = $i + 20;
        $this->load->view('static/print_header');
        $this->load->view('static/print_invoice', $data);
        $this->load->view('static/print_footer');
   }
}
```

Comment: But how should I tell with CSS "use header and Footer once again if needed"?

Comment: I add my invoice code too.
I understood your point but the item text has all the time a different length. So I can't make it just through sql table rows. I thought about to count chars and if the next item doesn't fit inside first page, it should create a second one.

Answer (score 0):

If trying to add header and footer on all pages try adding `<thead> and <tfoot>` elements. On using this it displays the top and bottom contents on all the pages Or you can use the css styles-

```
<thead>
// your header content 
</thead>
<tfoot>
//your footer content
</tfoot>
```

CSS

```
 #header {
      display: table-header-group;
    }

    #footer {
      display: table-footer-group;
    }
```